# How to add environment variable to server, run by cypress testing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, cypress, react-fullstack

My package.json file is

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"nodemon index.js\" \"PORT=3000 react-scripts start\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "server": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon index.js",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eslint": "eslint .",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "start:test": "NODE_ENV=test concurrently \"NODE_ENV=test nodemon index.js\" \"NODE_ENV=test PORT=3000 react-scripts start\""
  },
```

my creation of router in node app.js is

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  const testingRouter = require('./controllers/testing')
  app.use('/api/testing', testingRouter)
}
```

but when I run cypress test it complains that there is no such router. How can I make  NODE_ENV=test while calling  npm run cypress:open
command?

And how can I console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) to see what if it was passed to cypres process?

Answer (score 0):

solved

"start:test": "cross-env NODE_ENV==test concurrently \"cross-env NODE_ENV=test nodemon index.js\" \"cross-env NODE_ENV=test PORT=3000 react-scripts start\""

and
npm run start:test command in one command prompt, and run cypress in another